# How to create Django Model with combination of 2 models

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to create one Django models which is the combination of 2 models like,

```
class Employee(models.Model):
  emp_id = models.CharField(max_length=45, primary_key=True, null=False)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
  age = models.IntegerField()
  dob = models.DateField()
  addr = models.CharField(max_length=45)

class designtion(models.Model):
  emp_id = models.charField(max_length=45)
  role_name =  models.charField(max_length=45)
  starts_from = models.DateField()
  ends_on = models.DateField()
```

i want to create a combined models from these 2,

```
class EmpDetails(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
  role_name =  models.charField(max_length=45)
```

i am using **django-rest-framework** is their any best way to do like this?

Comment: How to link Employee with designtion?

Comment: instead of foreign key i am using emp_id it will relate designation with emp table primary key

Comment: Why you want a new model?If you just want the role_name of an employee in  your serializers,`serializers.SerializerMethodField()` and  will meet your requirements.

Comment: i want to get options from 3rd(combined tables) which is integrated fields.. and i need to do post. like mysql routines

Comment: can't help you.

Comment: check this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes

Answer (score 1):

If you want, you can try this.

**models.py**

```
class designtion(models.Model):
    emp_id = models.charField(max_length=45)
    role_name =  models.charField(max_length=45)
    starts_from = models.DateField()
    ends_on = models.DateField()
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, related_name="designition_employee")
```

**serializers.py**

```
from .models import designtion, EmpDetails
class DesigntionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    hr_employee = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='employee.name', read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = designtion
        exclude = ()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        name = validated_data.get('employee').name
        role_name = validated_data.get('role_name')
        EmpDetails.objects.create(name=name, role_name=role_name)
        return super(DesigntionSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
```

Do not forget migrate when added employee field to designtion model.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a many-to-many relationship for `Employee` and `designtion`(btw you should capitalize this), Django has support for [M2M Field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)
It basically create a JOIN table under the hood, but it give you all the methods you would need to perform lookup, creation, etc..

If you want future proof just in case you are moving away from Django and want all your models and methods reusable, then you can create your `EmpDetails` table manually like such:

```
class EmpDetails(models.Model):
    ... //other fields omitted, add as you need them
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
    designtion = models.ForeignKey(designtion)
```